# Why is this question about removing puTTy "off-topic?"

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438780/how-to-uninstall-putty-using-homebrew) was recently closed as off-topic.

The [help page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) lists several types of on-topic questions. Among them is the fourth bullet point: "third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products."

puTTy is clearly designed to be associated for use with Apple products.

Why was this question deemed off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The detailed explanation is visible to the OP and should also be visible to people with reputation 3,000 which grants the close and reopen vote privilege:

> Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Without further details, we have no way of knowing whether the user just forgot about https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uninstall+homebrew+package, whether they did run the appropriate command but got an error, or whether something else is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Closing for that reason is entirely appropriate.